# How to decide between two differential geometry journals

Tags: mathematics, journals

Suppose I have a result in the field of differential geometry (and geometric analysis) and I’m considering two different well-known journals by the same editor: Journal of Differential Geometry and Cambridge Journal of Mathematics.

I know how respectful is JDG journal and articles therein, and I was wondering how can I decide between them, based on their objective differences. Thank you!

(Hope not to end up with a shopping question, since I followed the piece of advice suggesting that I ask how to *distinguish between two journals*. Otherwise, please suggest how can I change it to save it).

Comment: Strongly related, possibly duplicate: [How to decide between sending paper to a specialized journal or to a journal with broader audience?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20130/546) Journal of Differential Geometry is specialized, Cambridge Journal of Mathematics has broader audience.

Comment: It's a shopping question because you're asking for a judgment between journals. As @Nobody points out there are already q&a here about making this sort of decision more generally.