# A journal with higher IF but general scope, or a journal with less IF but specialized scope?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, elsevier, acm

Which one is more valuable to send a paper (in computer science?

1. A journal with a general scope of computer science from Elsevier, with impact factor of around 8. H index around 140.
2. A journal with a specific scope, which is the scope of the paper. And is famous in that field and amoung the journals with that specific field. It is from ACM, with the impact factor of 2. H index around 30.

Both are Q1. And both have the same history in quartiles. I mean, both have been Q1 for many years, and before that they have been Q2, Q3 or so.

The time of review process and publication is not important for me.

Is there any other criteria that I should consider?

---

I found my answer some how in [this link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/how-to-decide-between-sending-paper-to-a-specialized-journal-or-to-a-journal-wit?rq=1). So I close my question.

Comment: More valuable to whom based on what criteria? Seems opinion-based.

Comment: For example, if I want to apply for a PHD position, which is more valuable to be in cv? For example, that's a common knowledge that most of the IEEE journals are valuable. Could you please compare them based on different critera?

Comment: Again, different folks will have different opinions. There is no universal ranking cheat sheet for PhD admissions in any field.

Comment: PHD admission was just an example. I think it is clear that if ones ask that whether "IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence" is more valuable or X (I don't name to not to insult any journal) nobody selects X. I want a same comparison if exist. Could you please tell me the criteria you consider?

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant to you, but, for me, in math in the U.S., for grad admissions, postdocs, and tenure-track stuff, I don't care too much about the specific journals (except possibly as vague, general indicators), nor even whether something has been peer-reviewed, but, rather, primarily, about the _CONTENT_ of the paper(s). Worry about gaming the system is really a very marginal approach...

Comment: @paul garrett: That's right. but don't you think that the value of the publisher helps to encourage/select to see the content or not? Doesn't it help to transfer the value of the paper easier?

Comment: @m123, in my world (which some might say is a bit contrarian), the status of the journal in which something appears has a very, very minor effect on my perception of its interest/value. It more indicates what _some_ people may think about it, but I'm more interested in my own assessment than in the opinions of people far away whom I might barely know. Extreme case (perhaps more special to math or theoretical physics): preprints on arXiv !!!  This is what I look at every day! :)

Comment: Also, not responding directly to the question, but, I think, a very important reframing: especially when I cannot really personally understand the significance of a line of work, I _am_ interested in the letters of recommendation from senior people, whose names (and reputations) I know, giving their appraisals. This is is more accurate than names-of-journals, in my experience. Maybe this is something peculiar to math in the U.S., I don't know.

Comment: @paul garrett: It is a nice sight to check the content, I hope many get the same as you. unfortunatelly, I have seen several people and several situations with opposite attitude.
About your last comment: sometimes we just want to check someone's profile who didn't applied for any position. I understand and thanks your excellent point of view, and it was helpful for me. But I am still trying to solely decide about the journal, independent of other factors.

Comment: I understand. But, then, still, I'd recommend not spending toooo much time on that decision, which could be better spent on doing actual work. :)

Comment: @Sursula: No, the link you sent, asks for the harms of publishing many papers in one specific journal. And in the answers there is only one sentence which can indirectly relate to my question. It says : _"However, it's not clear to me that the excellent but not top generalist journals (eg Math Zeitschrift) are clearly better than the best subject-specific journals."_ And based on its examples for top generalist journals (e.g. Acta), my option with general subject is not considered to be in the top list based on his view.

Comment: Strongly related: [How to decide between sending paper to a specialized journal or to a journal with broader audience?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20130/546)

Comment: @Nobody: Yes, it answers my question, I edited and add it to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score -3):

Depends on who is looking at your papers or CV.  I for example do not go by journal name as I know that's not 100% guarantee of quality.  Hence, I will read your papers and judge them myself.  Another researcher, say one that cannot produce high quality work, may go with the fact that the paper is in a Q1 journal.  Some researchers will only look at citations, and do not really care too much about where a paper appears.  Researchers outside the community or management may only count number of papers.  Yet some people will only care whether a paper has any practicality, i.e., led to a start up.

The 'successful' researchers will have all of the above; i.e., high number of papers, a subset of high quality and cited papers and maybe a start-up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148083/discussion-between-vitamine-and-earlgrey).